# Matlab 'svd' on N threads

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I know that `Matlab`'s `svd` function (as well as many other functions) are multithreaded by default. This is great when working on a desktop, but is not desirable for a cluster where many users are submitting jobs simultaneously and must request resources ahead of time. If a user attempt to run a `matlab` script with 1 core but calls `svd`, the job will use up to 20 cores on our machines when that is not their intent.

I would like to restrict such functions to a predefined, user initialized, number of threads. I know that you can restrict `matlab` to one thread by starting it with `singleCompThread` and then call a `parpool` with N threads, but I am not able to make `svd` use the workers.

Is there a way to, on a host with `M` cores, restrict "pre-multithreaded" functions to `N` cores where `1 < N < M` cores?

UPDATE:

I will go into a bit more depth about what the intent of this question is. We have a large cluster with GPU nodes, Hadoop systems, 250+ hosts with a combined 5000+ cores and 40+ TB of RAM and there is no reason why users should be sharing cpu cores if there are open cores available. Because of this, when a user submits a job, they tell our queueing system how many cores they want to use. If `userA` submits a multicore job and `userB` submits a multicore job, but neither tell our queueing system how many cores they want, it is possible that they will be placed on the same host. There may be other (idle) hosts, but these two are sharing the same host and hurting both of their performance

To this end, I would like our users to know how many cores they want to use and request that number of cores ahead of time. They can easily say they want all 20 cores on a machine and not worry about the fact that `matlab` will use all possible threads, but then they need to wait for an open machine, since they want every single core. A much better solution is to teach users how to run their code in parallel with a predefined number of cores and then tell our queueing system how many cores they need.

Another problem is that many of our users use 'bootstrapping' solutions so solve their problems where they want high-throughput for their jobs. Each individual job is single threaded, but they want to have thousands running at a time. In this case, it will actually *hurt* them to run their code in parallel (trust me on this).

So the question remains: How do I run `svd` or similar multithreaded functions with a pre-specified number of threads so that we can make sure the resources on our cluster are optimized for all of our users?

Comment: The cluster administrator will usually restrict the number of threads a process (especially matlab) can spawn. However, cluster computers are faster than Desktops **because** they have more CPU cores and typically more RAM per multicore CPU, and **not** because a single thread is faster there. noone will be happy to be forced to use a cluster if processing there is required to be singlethreaded -- that will typically be slower than doing it on your laptop!

Comment: _If a user attempt to run a matlab script with 1 core but calls svd, the job will use up to 20 cores on our machines_: is that a problem? If a second user requests a job, the system will probably time-share the resources between them

Comment: Haha, I'm the cluster administrator! I'm aware that a single threaded stream is slower but am working to teach the users how to run their code in multi threaded environment and make conscious decisions about what they choose. @LuisMendo  - yes, it is a problem - I'll update my question with the intent to explain more.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Restrict the effect of threading using processor affinitisation
2. Call [`maxNumCompThreads`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html)

Note that `maxNumCompThreads` is currently deprecated, which is a shame - but it is currently the best option.